# differences between clicking next button and hitting enter on jQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery validation form which doesn't let user go next until he fulfills the form.

Funny thing is user can't go further by pressing `Next` button but just can post the form by hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/r6sztnsh/1/

Going ahead and disabling user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> is another thing, but I want hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to do the same with clicking the `Next` button.

**Java Script:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        // Custom method to validate username
        $.validator.addMethod("usernameRegex", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/i.test(value);
        }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers");

        $(".next").click(function(){
            var form = $("#myform");
            form.validate({
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'help-block',
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
                },
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        usernameRegex: true,
                        minlength: 6,
                    },
                    password : {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    conf_password : {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: '#password',
                    },
                    company:{
                        required: true,
                    },
                    url:{
                        required: true,
                    },
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                    },

                },
                messages: {
                    username: {
                        required: "Username required",
                    },
                    password : {
                        required: "Password required",
                    },
                    conf_password : {
                        required: "Password required",
                        equalTo: "Password don't match",
                    },
                    name: {
                        required: "Name required",
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Email required",
                    },
                }
            });
            if (form.valid() === true){
                if ($('#account_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#account_information');
                    next_fs = $('#company_information');
                }else if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#company_information');
                    next_fs = $('#personal_information');
                }

                next_fs.show(); 
                current_fs.hide();
            }
        });

        $('#previous').click(function(){
            if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                current_fs = $('#company_information');
                next_fs = $('#account_information');
            }else if ($('#personal_information').is(":visible")){
                current_fs = $('#personal_information');
                next_fs = $('#company_information');
            }
            next_fs.show(); 
            current_fs.hide();
        });

    });
```

*

I guess magic will happen somewhere around `$(".next").click(function(){
            var form = $("#myform");` here :)

Any ideas on making hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the same as clicking the `Next`?

Comment: That's why it's better not to bind to the button at all and use the submit event to validate and send data. If you only rely on button you don't allow users to submit using keyboard

Comment: @charlietfl, Yes, that was my question. As I wrote above _Any ideas on making hitting the `Enter` with the same as clicking the `Next`?_ So I really don't want to only rely on button. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the enter key press to do the same thing clicking your next button does?  Based on your jsfiddle for you form:

```
$('.form-horizontal').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        $(".next").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great solution for user experience. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the submit if the form is not complete using the event 'submit' :

```
form.on('submit',fonction(pEvent){
    if(/* form not complete */) {
        pEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but what I tried to say is completely different. This prevents user to hit the `Enter`. What I am saying is making hitting `Enter` the same with pressing `Next` button. I am sure your answer will help somebody else out there ;)